# How to exclude values from a dataframe based on values in a second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2, example:

`df1`:

```
Date   ID        Value 
1/2/2013   001    1
2/5/2013   002    15
3/4/2013   001    2
1/1/2014   005    17
2/5/2014   004    1
7/1/2016   002    2
7/1/2016   001    4
8/1/2016   007    4
```

`df2`:

```
Year   ID  
2013   001    
2014   005     
2014   004  
2016   001
```

I want to get a dataframe where I remove the rows from df1 that has Year and ID combo in df2. For example, there is 2013 and 001 in df2, I would like to remove all values from df1 that has a date in 2013 and an ID of 001.

The resulting df3 would be:

`df3`:

```
Date   ID        Value 
2/5/2013   002    15
7/1/2016   002    2
8/1/2016   007    4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator=True` after Extracting the year from `Date`:

```
out = (df1
       .merge(df2, left_on=[pd.to_datetime(df1['Date']).dt.year, 'ID'],
              right_on=['Year', 'ID'], how='left',
              suffixes=(None, '_'), indicator=True)
       .query('_merge == "left_only"')[df1.columns]
      )
```

Output:

```
       Date   ID  Value
1  2/5/2013  002     15
5  7/1/2016  002      2
7  8/1/2016  007      4
```

Intermediate without `.query('_merge == "left_only"')[df1.columns]`:

```
       Date   ID  Value  Year     _merge
0  1/2/2013  001      1  2013       both
1  2/5/2013  002     15  2013  left_only
2  3/4/2013  001      2  2013       both
3  1/1/2014  005     17  2014       both
4  2/5/2014  004      1  2014       both
5  7/1/2016  002      2  2016  left_only
6  7/1/2016  001      4  2016       both
7  8/1/2016  007      4  2016  left_only
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df.loc[~pd.Series(zip(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.year,df['ID']),index = df.index).isin(df2.to_records(index=False))]
```

Output:

```
       Date  ID  Value
1  2/5/2013   2     15
5  7/1/2016   2      2
7  8/1/2016   7      4
```